# Permissions suddenly changed

Tags: configuration, debugging

I've inherited a drupal 7.6 site with a broken css (styles were not loading). Here's what I've done so far:

-set sites/default/files, tmp and cache folder to 777.
-flushed all caches

When this didn't work, I deleted the /files folder and created a new one which has done the trick.

I'm still getting "The file permissions could not be set on cache/normal/..." in recent log messages.
in the cache folder, I'm seeing html being created but there are a lot of "boostfRVyMR" and similarly named files.

Is there other permissions to be changed?

Comment: That sounds like a different folder than the one you mentioned at sites/default/files.

Comment: sorry I shortened the path - I meant I deleted sites/default/files and created a new one in it's place

Comment: Be sure that the server user having access to your drupal base folder (www/) is the same as the owner of the sites/default/files folder and subfolders.

Comment: that's interesting because it changes - the user for all files/folders is "XYZ" but some files/folders in sites/default//files including the .htaccess is "nobody". Is this an issue with Drupal or the web server?

Comment: I checked which user is running Apache by running this command 
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
all of the process are owned by "nobody" but all of the files are owned by "XYZ". I'm assuming this has been the cause.